# Python: import modules dynamically in different namespace

Tags: python, namespaces, import

```
import v_framework as framework
framework.loadModules(["Maintenance"])
framework.Maintenance.showPage()
```

In `framework` I have:

```
def loadModules(aModules):
    d_utility = {"Maintenance":"COOl_M_PAGE"}
    for module in a_aModules:
        exec("import " + d_utility[module] + " as " + module)
```

When `loadModules` is executed, it imports the modules in the `v_framework` namespace. Since I am importing `v_framework` as `framework`, I think I should be able to use the imported module using `framework.Maintenance`. But it does not work that way.
   Is there a way to do way to do what I'm trying to do? Alternatively, is there any way to import modules in a namespace other than the one where `exec` is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are libraries for importing modules dynamically. You could use [importlib](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/importlib.html) (and another one that might be useful is [pkgutil](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html)). Now, for your case, I guess this would do the job:

```
import importlib
mods = {}
def loadModules(aModule):
    global mods
    mods[module] = importlib.import_module(d_utility[module])
    # or maybe globals()[module] = ... would work also (exactly as you expect it to
```

UPDATE: exec modifies the function's local namespace, not the global one (I think).

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you `import` inside a function, the module is imported/executed as normal, but the name you import under is local to the function, just like any other variable assigned inside a function.

```
>>> def test_import():
...    import os
...    print os
...
>>> test_import()
<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
>>> os
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

`os` has been imported though, and you can still access it through `sys.modules`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['os']
<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
>>> os = sys.modules['os']
>>> os
<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
```

A quick and dirty way to do what you want would be something like this; `exec` takes an optional mapping to be used as the local and global variables. So you could do

```
def loadModules(aModules):
    d_utility = {"Maintenance":"COOl_M_PAGE"}
    for module in aModules:
        exec ('import %s as %s' % (d_utility[module], module)) in globals()
```

Though this is ugly and probably has security implications or something. As jadkik94 mentions, there are libraries that provide cleaner ways to deal with this.